# Joining 2 or More Database with 1 column result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

we're working academic database

column tabel mata_kuliah

```
id
nm_mk
kode_mk
```

values tabel mata_kuliah

```
id   | nm_mk       | kode_mk
1    | algoritma   | TI001
2    | databases   | TI002
3    | java        | TI003
4    | OOP         | TI004
5    | theses      | TI005
```

column tabel mahasiswa

```
id_mhs
nm_mhs
npm_mhs
```

values tabel mahasiswa

```
id   | nm_mhs      | npm_mhs
1    | Andi        | 18.14.1.0001
2    | Soraya      | 18.14.1.0002
3    | Mumun       | 18.14.1.0003
4    | Dede        | 18.14.1.0004
5    | Udin        | 18.14.1.0005
```

we're moving from previous db to the new one, on result we have to call another table for 1 result (academic result)

column nilai_lama

```
id_nilai_lama
id_mk
id_mhs
nilai_mk
```

column nilai_baru

```
id_nilai_baru
id_mk
id_mhs
nilai_mk
```

column nilai_konversi

```
id_nilai_konversi
id_mk
npm_mhs
nilai_mk
```

values tabel nilai_lama

```
id_nilai_lama   | id_mk | npm_mhs       | nilai_mk
1               | 1     | 18.14.1.0001  | 3
2               | 1     | 18.14.1.0002  | 4
3               | 1     | 18.14.1.0003  | 3
4               | 1     | 18.14.1.0004  | 3
5               | 1     | 18.14.1.0005  | 4
```

values tabel nilai_baru

```
id_nilai_baru   | id_mk | npm_mhs       | nilai_mk
1               | 2     | 18.14.1.0001  | 3
2               | 2     | 18.14.1.0002  | 4
3               | 2     | 18.14.1.0003  | 3
4               | 2     | 18.14.1.0004  | 3
5               | 2     | 18.14.1.0005  | 4
6               | 1     | 18.14.1.0001  | 4 (same id_mk, npm_mhs but hihger nilai_mk)
```

values tabel nilai_konversi

```
id_nilai_konversi   | id_mk | npm_mhs       | nilai_mk
1                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0001  | 3
2                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0002  | 4
3                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0003  | 3
4                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0004  | 3
5                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0005  | 4
6                   | 3     | 18.14.1.0003  | 4 (take course twice but diff result)
```

Query

```
select 
  a.id_mk,
  b.nilai_mk,
  b.npm_mhs 
from 
  mata_kuliah a 
left join 
  (
    (select id_mk,max(nilai_mk),npm_mhs from nilai_lama group by id_mk)
or
    (select id_mk,max(nilai_mk),npm_mhs from nilai_baru group by id_mk)
or
    (select id_mk,max(nilai_mk),npm_mhs from nilai_konversi group by id_mk)
  ) b
on 
  a.id_mk=b.id_mk and npm_mhs=?
```

expected result npm_mhs = 18.14.1.0001

```
id_mk | nilai_mk | npm_mhs
1     | 4        | 18.14.1.0001 (value in nilai_baru is higher)
2     | 3        | 18.14.1.0001
3     | 3        | 18.14.1.0001
```

expected result npm_mhs = 18.14.1.0003

```
id_mk | nilai_mk | npm_mhs
1     | 3        | 18.14.1.0003 
2     | 4        | 18.14.1.0003 (has twice result in same tabel)
3     | 3        | 18.14.1.0003
```

is this possible to do?

Comment: In your table nilai_baru, all id_mk value should be 2? or last value 1 is expected?

Comment: Only 1 expected with higher value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this query? There are some mismatch in the output considering your expected output. But if I guess In your table nilai_baru, all id_mk value is 2 and output for 18.14.1.0003 will be as below, the query should work for your.

```
1     | 3        | 18.14.1.0003 
2     | 3        | 18.14.1.0003
3     | 4        | 18.14.1.0003 (has twice result in same tabel)
```

The query is-

```
SELECT id_mk, npm_mhs, MAX(nilai_mk)  
FROM
(
    SELECT id_mk, npm_mhs, nilai_mk FROM nilai_lama
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id_mk, npm_mhs, nilai_mk FROM nilai_baru
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id_mk, npm_mhs, nilai_mk FROM nilai_konversi
)A
WHERE A.npm_mhs = '18.14.1.0003'
GROUP BY id_mk,npm_mhs
```

Comment: This query inside left join. I'll try it